# zend Pagination without fetching query again for each page

Tags: performance, zend-framework, pagination

Is it possible to use zend pagination without calling the query every time i request a page from the pager?

When I hit a page number from the pager a request to the zzAction below is done and the query is fetched again. My query is huge and I don't want to fetch the query all over again. Am I missing something in the code.

Code:

Controller:

```
public function getOnePageOfEntries($array, $page=1) {
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($array); 
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(6);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    return $paginator;
}
public function zzAction() {
   ...

    $tt= $this->yyObject->xx(....);

    $paginator = $this -> getOnePageOfEntries($tt, $page);
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;

}
```

Model:

```
public function xx(...){

    try{
        ...

        $stmt = $this->prepare("CALL sp_yy(...)");
        ....

                    $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();


        if (is_null($result)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $result;

    }catch (ErrorsException $obj){
                echo $obj;exit;
    }//end try
}
```

View:

```
<?php
$config = Zend_Registry::get('appsConfig');
?>
<?php if (count($this->paginator)){ ?>

<?php foreach($this->paginator as $cc){ ?>
<?php echo $cc['id'] . '/';?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator,
'Sliding','ff/my_pagination_control.phtml'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Zend_Paginator_Adapater_DbSelect();

example:

```
    $adapter     = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($data); //$data is database query
    $pagination  = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```

See more here:

[Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html)

Comment: thanks. But I am worried about performance because a second query is dynamically generated to determine the total number of matching rows (as per the link provided) plus it will call the select statement all over again for each page (although it will just get some records). That's why I was thinking to select only some records using a limit clause but I want to avoid calling the procedure again when fetching the new page. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect supports LIMIT, OFFSET automatically .don't worry about that. it only fetch data with number of records as your ItemsCountPerPage, not fetchall.

_Sorry i speak English not well_

Answer (score 0):

Your current code artificially limits the utility of the *array* adapter and forces you to execute the whole query for every page. What you need to accomplish in your controller actions that consume this paginator is to only execute the query if the data doesn't already exist. Maybe something similar to:

```
//consider this to psuedocode as it has not been tested a represents an idea
public function zzAction()
{ 
    //get page number
    $page = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
    //set session namespace, probably better to do this in init() method or bootstrap
    $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('paged')
    //test for presence of persisted array
    if (!isset($session->paginator)) {
        //perform query
        $arrayToPage = $this->yyObject->xx(....);
        //persist result array
        $session->paginator = $arrayToPage;
    } else {
        //retrieve persisted array
        $arrayToPage = $session->paginator;
    }

    $paginator = $this -> getOnePageOfEntries($arrayToPage, $page);
    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;

}
```

Using the DbTableSelect or DbSelect paginator adapter is often far more effiecient as it only queries for the data need to populate a specific page. This is very useful when your user wants to go form page 1 to page 7 ...

Another consideration when using a paginator is custom entity models. This is fairly easy to deal with in ZF:

```
<?php
class Record_Model_Paginator_Record extends Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect
{
    //override getItems to customize the adapter to use a specific mapper to create entities
    public function getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage)
    {
        $rows = parent::getItems($offset, $itemCountPerPage);

        $record = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            //initiate mapper
            $recordEntity = new Application_Model_Mapper_Record();
            //create entity models
            $record[] = $recordEntity->createEntity($row);
        }
        //returns an array of objects, similar to a Zend_Db_Rowset object
        return $record;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.